# Disassemble a flatfile with BizTalk, when record contains nulls

Tags: character-encoding, xsd, biztalk, flat-file

An external partner will be sending us comma-separated files containing purchase orders, which we need to process in our BizTalk environment. I will be using BizTalk's flatfile disassembler to transform the csv data into workable xml.

However, many of the records in our partner's files have null values for certain 'columns' (e.g. not all address fields have a value). Upon disassembly by BizTalk using the flatfile xsd (created with the wizard in Visual Studio), the resulting xml contains elements like this:

`<ShipToAddress2>&#x0;</ShipToAddress2>`

And our subsequent mappings fails with

> System.Xml.XmlException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.

In what way can I eliminate this error? Is there a property in the flatfile xsd, or a setting in the disassember in which I can set the behaviour for handling null values in the data?

Comment: A bit dirty, but you can specify a padding character (type Hexadecimal, value `0x00`) for the relevant fields. That way the zero characters will be stripped during disassembly.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ indeed appears to be a more structural solution. I would have to invest some more time in a pipeline component that would strip a number of charactesr (including ```0x00``` and ```0x19```). At this point though, I will take Ruud's answer for the short term fix, but will consider your suggestion for a structural solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relevant fields don't already have a padding character set, you can use that to strip the zero characters during disassembly.

For every field that requires it first set the `Pad Character Type` to `Hexadecimal`, then `Pad Character` to `0x00`.

[image: Visual Studio setting]

Comment: I can confirm this works as described. And for clarity; setting the default pad character for the entirety of the of the xsd is not sufficient; it must indeed be set at each individual field.

Comment: @cordifed If you set a default pad character on the schema, you still have to set `Pad Character Type` to `Default Pad Character` for every field that requires it.